Add Vuforia Model Targets at runtime
I want to create an app on Magic Leap 2 using Unity and Vuforia, to detect model targets. Is there any way for the user to upload and create a new model target from within the app? Or are all the model targets predefined in the build, and created through Vuforia's model target generator?
I searched through the documentation, and it seems that only Image Targets can be added in runtime.

You can create a Model Target via this Web API https://developer.vuforia.com/library/web-api/model-target-web-api
Then it is possible to load it and use it at runtime via the standard Engine API as explained here
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/unity-extension/create-and-load-targets-unity

from what I know about Vuforia(I made a project with once)
you have to import your Vuforia database package into your unity project. And because of that you kinda have to release a new build for new image model you add.
